# How to reduce noise on transparent animation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, light, noise-reduction

I am making an animation(in cycles render) where object is converting from diffuse to transparent(with 0.9 value on mix shader). I am using branched path tracing (with square samples)
[image: Settings Screenshot]
Below is the rendering sample. All rendering is good except for the transparent part.[image: Rendering Sample]

I am using Diffuse material with Transparent material(mix shader value changes from 0 to 0.9 in animation)

Below is the shader window.
[image]

Its taking 2mins per frame.
How to make it look perfect in this render time?

Comment: Do you actually have any volumetrics in there? You shouldn't expect a render time of 2 mins if the volume bounces are set to 2 (provided you have volumetrics).

Comment: No I don't have any volumetrics in the scene. But my scene is a little big. Its just a part of it.

Answer (score 7):

Try enabling *Transparent Shadows* in *Properties > Render > Light Paths*:

[image]

This setting enables an optimization which greatly reduces noise in shadows cast by partially transparent objects, at the cost of some speed.

Here's a comparison rendered with sampling settings identical to yours (except for the shadow setting of course).

With *Shadows* disabled (1:59):

[image]

With *Shadows* enabled (2:11):

[image]

Note that you can also disable this option per-material via the *Transparent Shadows* setting in *Properties > Materials > Settings*

Comment: If I enable shadows, my display driver is crashing.

Comment: @Prasoon Then solve that problem. Your "display driver...crashing" is not a reason to reject the actual Blender solution. If this is what fixes it (and by the number of votes it has it looks like it probably does), then just look into the driver problem so you can use it.

Comment: I did two things & the problem is now solved without enabling shadows.

Comment: @Prasoon I must admit, cycles causing a driver crash is not something I've experienced before ;) Are you using GPU rendering? Does this occur with a nightly build of blender? If so, I'd consider submitting a [bug report](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/599)

Comment: @gandalf3 Ya I am using GPU rendering with Blender version 2.77a.But I not sure its a blender issue or I am using wrong settings to render. As the *.blend file size for this animation is 300MB. I think size may be the issue.

Comment: @Prasoon Well, even invalid settings should never cause any sort of crash, in theory anyway. They sometimes do, and that's what bug reports are for. Even if its the GPU drivers and not blender doing the crashing, if it can be consistently reproduced, there's no harm in letting the devs know. But if your scene just doesn't fit in GPU memory then that's different (and not a bug). It should display some kind of message like "Ran out of CUDA memory" if this is the case. Regardless, I'm glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I removed checkmarks except for camera in object properties.[image]

Next I removed the tick mark from Transparent shadows in material properties.
[image]

Now my final rendering is coming like below. Rendering time is little bit more but that's OK.
[image]

Thanks for the help @gandalf3